# Signal strength automatically reverts back to great when you set it poor or moderate in Android studio virtual device for version> 10

Tags: android, android-studio, testing

Signal strength automatically reverts back to great when you set it poor,great,moderate, I'm testing for signal strength value where I have to test it in various Signal strengths great,good,moderate,poor,none.So when I switched to moderate,poor,none it changes back to great in Android version> 10 whereas in version <10 it doesn't revert back.

So is there a way that signal strength doesn't revert to great when you set it moderate,poor for Android version>10 in Android studio virtual device.In version<10 it doesn't revert back to great signal signal strength when you set it moderate, poor signal strength.I want to test it in device>10 where the signal strength doesn't revert back when you set it to none,poor,moderate. Could you guys please help me out on this.

Comment: Can you add your procedure, network type etc info, and some video of this behaviour?